# Relationship between two orthogonal vectors ( i.e. $u \cdot v = 0$) and the inner product $u^TMv$ where $M$ positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are orthogonal wrt the standard inner product, then is there something that can be said about the inner product $\langle u,v \rangle_M = u^TMv$ where $M$ is a positive definite matrix?

In general, I would like to know if there exists a result like $\langle u,v \rangle_M \geq 0$ or $\langle u,v \rangle_M = 0$. Many thanks for any responses

Comment: No, there are no results like those. You can see for yourself decomposing the matrix $M$ as $O\Lambda O^T$, where $O$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries.

Comment: We do have $|u^TMv|\le\|M\|\|u\|\|v\|=\rho(M)\|u\|\|v\|$, but this is pretty uninteresting.

Comment: good to know, thanks for the help!